# How to make multicolor line in Chart.js 2.9.3

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js 2.9.3 and I need to make line time chart with different color.
I found this solution (https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/BWxErp?editors=0010) and it works, but only for version 2.5.0.

here is my code with chart.js version 2.9.3:

```js
// decimal rounding algorithm
// see: https://plnkr.co/edit/uau8BlS1cqbvWPCHJeOy?p=preview
var roundNumber = function (num, scale) {
  var number = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, scale)) / Math.pow(10, scale);
  if(num - number > 0) {
    return (number + Math.floor(2 * Math.round((num - number) * Math.pow(10, (scale + 1))) / 10) / Math.pow(10, scale));
  } else {
    return number;
  }
};

// save the original line element so we can still call it's 
// draw method after we build the linear gradient
var origLineElement = Chart.elements.Line;

// define a new line draw method so that we can build a linear gradient
// based on the position of each point
Chart.elements.Line = Chart.Element.extend({
  draw: function() {
    var vm = this._view;
    var backgroundColors = this._chart.controller.data.datasets[this._datasetIndex].backgroundColor;
    var points = this._children;
    var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
    var minX = points[0]._model.x;
    var maxX = points[points.length - 1]._model.x;
    var linearGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(minX, 0, maxX, 0);

    // iterate over each point to build the gradient
    points.forEach(function(point, i) {
      // `addColorStop` expects a number between 0 and 1, so we
      // have to normalize the x position of each point between 0 and 1
      // and round to make sure the positioning isn't too percise 
      // (otherwise it won't line up with the point position)
      var colorStopPosition = roundNumber((point._model.x - minX) / (maxX - minX), 2);

      // special case for the first color stop
      if (i === 0) {
        linearGradient.addColorStop(0, backgroundColors[i]);
      } else {
        // only add a color stop if the color is different
        if (backgroundColors[i] !== backgroundColors[i-1]) {
          // add a color stop for the prev color and for the new color at the same location
          // this gives a solid color gradient instead of a gradient that fades to the next color
          linearGradient.addColorStop(colorStopPosition, backgroundColors[i - 1]);
          linearGradient.addColorStop(colorStopPosition, backgroundColors[i]);
        }
      }
    });

    // save the linear gradient in background color property
    // since this is what is used for ctx.fillStyle when the fill is rendered
    vm.backgroundColor = linearGradient;

    // now draw the lines (using the original draw method)
    origLineElement.prototype.draw.apply(this);
  }               
});

// we have to overwrite the datasetElementType property in the line controller
// because it is set before we can extend the line element (this ensures that 
// the line element used by the chart is the one that we extended above)
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  datasetElementType: Chart.elements.Line,
});

// the labels used by the chart
var labels = [moment("2/17/2020 22:54"), moment("2/18/2020 23:20"), moment("2/19/2020 20:18"), moment("2/20/2020 23:02"), moment("2/21/2020 22:59"), moment("2/23/2020 23:07"), moment("2/28/2020 21:32"), moment("2/29/2020 23:31"), moment("3/10/2020 20:34"), moment("3/11/2020 22:53"), moment("3/13/2020 01:03"), moment("3/13/2020 19:38"), moment("3/14/2020 22:09"), moment("3/15/2020 20:12"), moment("3/16/2020 22:53"), moment("3/17/2020 20:56"), moment("3/18/2020 23:04"), moment("3/19/2020 23:05"), moment("3/26/2020 23:28"), moment("3/27/2020 22:13")];

// the line chart point data
var lineData = [255, 194.5, 208, 199.5, 269, 238.5, 194.5, 292.5, 741.5, 693.5, 464.5, 195.5, 200, 312.5, 197.5, 177, 118.5, 217, 263.5, 268.5];

// colors used as the point background colors as well as the fill colors
var fillColors = ["rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)"];

// get the canvas context and draw the chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      backgroundColor: fillColors, // now we can pass in an array of colors (before it was only 1 color)
      borderColor: "rgba(0,190,165)",
      pointBackgroundColor: fillColors,
      fill: true,
      data: lineData
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text:'Chart.js - Line Chart With Colored Fill Regions'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
          type: 'time',
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Date'
      },
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

and here is the same code with chart.js version 2.5.0 (it works properly):

```js
// decimal rounding algorithm
// see: https://plnkr.co/edit/uau8BlS1cqbvWPCHJeOy?p=preview
var roundNumber = function (num, scale) {
  var number = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, scale)) / Math.pow(10, scale);
  if(num - number > 0) {
    return (number + Math.floor(2 * Math.round((num - number) * Math.pow(10, (scale + 1))) / 10) / Math.pow(10, scale));
  } else {
    return number;
  }
};

// save the original line element so we can still call it's 
// draw method after we build the linear gradient
var origLineElement = Chart.elements.Line;

// define a new line draw method so that we can build a linear gradient
// based on the position of each point
Chart.elements.Line = Chart.Element.extend({
  draw: function() {
    var vm = this._view;
    var backgroundColors = this._chart.controller.data.datasets[this._datasetIndex].backgroundColor;
    var points = this._children;
    var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
    var minX = points[0]._model.x;
    var maxX = points[points.length - 1]._model.x;
    var linearGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(minX, 0, maxX, 0);

    // iterate over each point to build the gradient
    points.forEach(function(point, i) {
      // `addColorStop` expects a number between 0 and 1, so we
      // have to normalize the x position of each point between 0 and 1
      // and round to make sure the positioning isn't too percise 
      // (otherwise it won't line up with the point position)
      var colorStopPosition = roundNumber((point._model.x - minX) / (maxX - minX), 2);

      // special case for the first color stop
      if (i === 0) {
        linearGradient.addColorStop(0, backgroundColors[i]);
      } else {
        // only add a color stop if the color is different
        if (backgroundColors[i] !== backgroundColors[i-1]) {
          // add a color stop for the prev color and for the new color at the same location
          // this gives a solid color gradient instead of a gradient that fades to the next color
          linearGradient.addColorStop(colorStopPosition, backgroundColors[i - 1]);
          linearGradient.addColorStop(colorStopPosition, backgroundColors[i]);
        }
      }
    });

    // save the linear gradient in background color property
    // since this is what is used for ctx.fillStyle when the fill is rendered
    vm.backgroundColor = linearGradient;

    // now draw the lines (using the original draw method)
    origLineElement.prototype.draw.apply(this);
  }               
});

// we have to overwrite the datasetElementType property in the line controller
// because it is set before we can extend the line element (this ensures that 
// the line element used by the chart is the one that we extended above)
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  datasetElementType: Chart.elements.Line,
});

// the labels used by the chart
var labels = [moment("2/17/2020 22:54"), moment("2/18/2020 23:20"), moment("2/19/2020 20:18"), moment("2/20/2020 23:02"), moment("2/21/2020 22:59"), moment("2/23/2020 23:07"), moment("2/28/2020 21:32"), moment("2/29/2020 23:31"), moment("3/10/2020 20:34"), moment("3/11/2020 22:53"), moment("3/13/2020 01:03"), moment("3/13/2020 19:38"), moment("3/14/2020 22:09"), moment("3/15/2020 20:12"), moment("3/16/2020 22:53"), moment("3/17/2020 20:56"), moment("3/18/2020 23:04"), moment("3/19/2020 23:05"), moment("3/26/2020 23:28"), moment("3/27/2020 22:13")];

// the line chart point data
var lineData = [255, 194.5, 208, 199.5, 269, 238.5, 194.5, 292.5, 741.5, 693.5, 464.5, 195.5, 200, 312.5, 197.5, 177, 118.5, 217, 263.5, 268.5];

// colors used as the point background colors as well as the fill colors
var fillColors = ["rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)", "rgba(0,190,165,.5)", "rgba(255,111,121,.5)"];

// get the canvas context and draw the chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      backgroundColor: fillColors, // now we can pass in an array of colors (before it was only 1 color)
      borderColor: "rgba(0,190,165)",
      pointBackgroundColor: fillColors,
      fill: true,
      data: lineData
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text:'Chart.js - Line Chart With Colored Fill Regions'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
          type: 'time',
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Date'
      },
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Can someone help me find where could be problem?

I'm not sure if this is version problem or something is missing in my code for newest version.